# Change directory permission from 000 to 0755

Tags: linux, permissions, linux-server

I’ve set `000` permission to my server’s directory. Now I’m not able to perform any operation on this directory.

I tried to change permission to `0755` using filezilla but I’m getting **Access Denied** error.

I also tried to change permission from cPanel - file manager but I’m getting same error.

How can I reset the permissions of this directory.

Comment: did you try command line `sudo` ? In this way you can become root (if you are a sudo-er) and then (I think) root can change the permissions: `sudo chmod 0755 /mydir`

Comment: This must be it, because I can easily change my perms from 755 to 000 and back, without any problems, on both files and dirs; I just tested it.

Comment: @gogoud I changed permission using filezilla.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae  Do you know solution? than pls explain.

Comment: No, what I am saying is that I cannot reproduce your problem.  You should try what `gogoud` suggested.

Comment: @gogoud : As you suggest, I tried to connect ftp using terminal and I'm getting same error. **Permission Denied.**